# Sticky table + table thead

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, sticky

I have this code and I need sticky `.tab1` and for `.tab2` just sticky `thead`. I'm going to use it for more tables so I need a little bit responsive code and if it would be possible flexible(resizing) width.

I tried some codes but they were not with responsive code, flexible width or code was harder than he had to be, I think.

There is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/st0skm1d/)

```
<div>
Header
</div>
<table class="tab1">
    <tr>
        <td>NAME</td>
        <td>
      <input type="text" size='20'>
          <input class="button" type="submit" name="button" value="search">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="tab2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>one</th>
            <th>two</th>
            <th>three</th>
            <th>four</th>
            <th>five</th>
            <th>six</th>
            <th>seven</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean fixed header?

Comment: for example like.. https://codepen.io/_codemics/pen/PwEbYJ but with conditions as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fabulous css sticky works best on stuff with display: block. You can fix this with a small piece of jquery, like this:

```js
$(function() {

$('table, td, th, thead').width(function() { 
    return $(this).width();
});

$('td, th, table, thead').height(function() { 
    return $(this).height();
});

$('table, thead').css('display','block')

});
```

```css
table{width:100%;}
div{padding:100px;}
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}

.tab1 {
position: sticky;
top: 0px;}

.tab2 thead {
position: sticky;
top: 20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Header
</div>
<table class="tab1">
 <tr>
  <td>BAR</td>
  <td>
      <input name='bar' type="text" readonly="readonly" size='20'>
    </td>
  <td>NAME</td>
  <td>
      <input type="text" size='20'>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="button" value="search">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table class="tab2">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>one</th>
   <th>two</th>
   <th>three</th>
   <th>four</th>
   <th>five</th>
   <th>six</th>
   <th>seven</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td><td>abcd</td>
 </tr>

</table><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```